# React pass prop as function then call it error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component A

```
resetSelectedDates = () => {
    this.setState({
        from_date: null,
        to_date: null
    })
}

render(){
   return(
      <Calendar resetDatePicker={this.resetSelectedDates} />
   )
}
```

as you can see it passed a function to component B

In component B I call the function like this

```
    fire(){
        this.props.resetDatePicker.call(null)
    }

<a onClick={this.fire.bind(this)}>Fire</a>
```

I got error of `Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

But in my constructor of component B I did have `resetDatePicker` when I do console.log

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: I am able to execute the code provided by you successfully, I think the problem is elsewhere, can you provide you complete component code

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your component B:

```
<a onClick={() => this.props.resetDatePicker()}>Fire</a>
```